# Load XML File in Oracle using SQL Loader

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

What should be the control file to load below 2 formats of XML . If there is any data then i will receive 
first format with open and close tag

```
<NAME>OTC</NAME>
```

if there is no data then i will receive second format .

```
<NAME/>
```

CTL FIle :

```
 LOAD DATA infile 'XML_out.xml' "str '</ROWSET>'" 
APPEND INTO TABLE SHM.REF_NAME TRAILING NULLCOLS 
( 
dummy filler char(1000) terminated by "<ROWSET>", 
NAME char(1000) enclosed by "<NAME>" and "</NAME>" 
)
```

However i am getting error:

> Initial enclosure character not found which is for second format.

Comment: I'll 2nd that question.  I'd like to know if it is possible to accommodate for empty nodes in ```sqlldr```.  I imagine there is some NULL condition that can be used, but I have not found any documentation around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i workaround by XSTL write output as html

```
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

Code : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHg/2

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible in SQLLDR directly.  Take a look at this thread.

[Can Oracle SQL*Loader process XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210944/can-oracle-sqlloader-process-xml/12222297?noredirect=1#comment104175849_12222297)

Comment: , After XSTL transformation only  i am getting above two formats